# How to manage timeout using httpWebRequest and method BeginGetRequestStream Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, timeout

I have this example working but I want to know how manage timeout for this example exactly. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

```
public void callREST()
{

Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/RestService"); 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";    

request.BeginGetRequestStream(sendXML_RequestCallback, request);                  

}

private void sendXML_RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var req = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

    byte[] toSign = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("<xml></xml>");

    using (var strm = req.EndGetRequestStream(result))
    {
        strm.Write(toSign, 0, toSign.Length);
        strm.Flush();
    }
req.BeginGetResponse(this.fCallback, req);
}

private void fCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
     var req = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;                
     var resp = req.EndGetResponse(result);
     var strm = resp.GetResponseStream();
     //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timeout` isn't supported as part of HttpWebRequest in Silverlight / Windows Phone 7.

You'll need to create a `Timer` and start that at the same time you start the request. If the timer fires before the HWR returns then `Abort()` the request and assume it timed out.

For more details and an example, see: [HttpWebRequest Timeout in WP7 not working with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554243/httpwebrequest-timeout-in-wp7-not-working-with-timer/5559459#5559459)

Comment: Yes, but I have two async methods, the response is done in two times. Maybe I should manage two timers ?
What method should stop timer ?  
sendXML_RequestCallback or fCallback ?

Comment: Use one timer. Stop the timer when you are happy the method has completed. This will probably be when you've got a response. It depends on what you are implementing the timeout for.