# How to increase HttpWebRequest timeout in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, windows-phone

Is there a way to increase Timeout in HttpWebRequest in Windows Phone 7 Application ?!

Answer (score 0):

if you are not doing it in a multithreaded program then you can do like this. ( C#) example.

```
 HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
 webReq.Timeout = 7000;
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
```

Comment: There is no Timeout property in Windows Phone.

Comment: Yes, Windos Phone does not support timeout property so you have to handle this manually. See step 4 in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh221581.aspx                                                Also Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554243/httpwebrequest-timeout-in-wp7-not-working-with-timer/5559459#5559459